# Using a Facebook like button inside an underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, facebook, underscore.js

I'm using an Underscore.js template to dynamically load or replace a video followed by some social media buttons and a video summary.

The problem is that the social media buttons do not load when the template is called and the content is replaced.

Is this because those buttons need some Javascript to initiate them, which is provided on page load but doesn't happen when the template is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FBXML:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

This will render out the social button.